Can I call the main function from an imported module?
I want to write a program to receive stock data from an API then do something. However, I couldn't return data from the API. Can someone help me to return data from other module or call the main function from other module?
main.py:
import SolPYAPI

def do_something():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SolPYAPI.quote('stock_name', 1000)

SolPYAPI.py:
from PY_Trade_package.MarketDataMart import MarketDataMart

# The API will continued receive matchprice and execution Event_OnMath()
def Event_OnMath(data):
    print(data.MatchPrice)

class Sample_D:
    _prod:str=""
    _sec:int = 0
    def run():
        fQuoteEvent = MarketDataMart()
        fQuoteEvent.OnMatch = Event_OnMath
        # delete much code...

def quote('stock_name', sec):
    Sample_D._prod = 'stock_name'
    Sample_D._sec = sec
    Sample_D.run()

Is there any way that 1 or 2 can be achieved?

can return data.MatchPrice to main.py when Event_OnMath(data) was call in SolPYAPI.py
can call do_somethin function in main.py when Event_OnMath(data) was call in SolPYAPI.py

I try to import main, like below:
SolPYAPI.py:
import main
def Event_OnMath(data):
    print(data.MatchPrice)
    main.do_something(data.MatchPrice)

however, it show some problems when I import main

"It show some problems" - please [edit] your question to include the full error message, including the traceback, as plain text.

there is a syntax error in the definition of quote

Remove single quote
 def quote(stock_name, sec):
    Sample_D._prod = stock_name

